# Strange message in terminal - virus?

Tags: gnome-terminal, malware

Should I be worried about this appearing in my terminal repeatedly:

```
2341:2341:0504/210750:ERROR:data_type_manager_impl.cc(34)] Passwords cryptographer error was encountered:`
`** Message: Remote error from secret service: org.freedesktop.Secret.Error.IsLocked: Cannot get secret of a locked object
`?
```

Comment: Repeatedly when? Does this message just appear randomly?

Comment: Today just once, when I used `google-chrome test.html` from the terminal. No mention today of the second part, with org.free.desktop. Worrying though, sounds just like the kind of url associated with malware.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a confirmed Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=408007